# GEM5 Simulation using HMC memory structure

Tags: gem5

I am new of GEM5.
I have a problem for GEM5 simulation.

I am working for simulation using HMC memory structure.

And I simulated with the command that:
gem5$./build/X86/gem5.opt ./config/example/hmctest.py

However, this simulation gave me an error like:
panic: Memory Size not divisible by page size

To solve this problem, I referred the web site (https://gem5-review.googlesource.com/c/public/gem5/+/6061 ), but it could not solve my error...

Is there any body who can give me some advice?

I will wait for your help!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet the same problem. After reading the code, I found that this error occurs because there is a bug in HMC.py when defining the address ranges of HMC memory devices and serial links: the end address of an address range is not inclusive in gem5 by default (for more details, you could check addr_range.hh). However, in HMC.py, it considers the end address is inclusive so "-1" is added when defining addr ranges.

The easiest way to solve this problem is remove all "-1" when defining "ser_ranges", "ser_rangeX" and "addr_ranges_vaults" in HMC.py. In this way, you don't need to recompile gem5 at all. I've tried it and it works!